# Issue with CORS configuration on Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, cors, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to build Gateway proxy using Spring Cloud Gateway.

I am able to route my requests to respective services using RouteLocator in Spring Cloud. But I am not able to configure CORS for the paths which are routing through RouteLocator.

I tried all the possibilities which are mentioned in the Spring Cloud document.

I am facing following error in my webpage:
[image]

My code looks like 
**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

// tag::route-locator[]
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route(p -> p
                    .path("/order/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.setResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081")
                    )
                    .uri("http://localhost:9090"))
            .route(p -> p
                    .path("/priority-model/selection/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.addResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081")
                    )
                    .uri("http://localhost:9090"))
            .build();
}

}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
```

**buils.gradle**

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-gateway'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.SR2"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-stub-runner"){
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-web"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-gateway-webflux', version: '2.0.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Comment: By default, API Gateway enables CORS for all the origins, if you want to allow only whitelisted origins then use globalcors configurations.                                           `spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

By default, API Gateway enables CORS for all the origins, if you want to allow only whitelisted origins then use globalcors configurations.
`spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET`

Comment: You should use specifig origins for the whitelist, "*" means any origin :)

Comment: it doesn't work at m

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
Using Ilford (Spring Cloud 2020.0.1)
and Spring cloud Gateway 3.0.0

The preflight request (OPTIONS) is always rejected with configuration

Only solution is by doind it with code adding a new Bean as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148481/12392086)