# How to disable global CORS config in Spring Cloud Gateway .yml config to allow requests from any origin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I want to create a gateway service for my microservice app and I add the configs that mentioned in spring cloud gateway documentation to disable CORS in the gateway:

```
spring:
  # GATEWAY CONFIG
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods: "*"
```

But I still get 403 Forbidden Error.
Am I wrong in the configurations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the below class

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsUtils;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
/**
 * @author Thirumal
 */
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration {

  private static final String ALLOWED_HEADERS = "x-requested-with, authorization, Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization, credential, X-XSRF-TOKEN";
  private static final String ALLOWED_METHODS = "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH";
  private static final String ALLOWED_ORIGIN = "*";
  private static final String MAX_AGE = "7200"; //2 hours (2 * 60 * 60) 

  @Bean
  public WebFilter corsFilter() {
    return (ServerWebExchange ctx, WebFilterChain chain) -> {
      ServerHttpRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
      if (CorsUtils.isCorsRequest(request)) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = ctx.getResponse();
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", ALLOWED_METHODS);
        headers.add("Access-Control-Max-Age", MAX_AGE); //OPTION how long the results of a preflight request (that is the information contained in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers) can be cached. 
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",ALLOWED_HEADERS);
        if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.OPTIONS) {
          response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
          return Mono.empty();
        }
      }
      return chain.filter(ctx);
    };
  }

}
```

Comment: why is this necessary? I'm about to try it, since I am getting 404s on my gateway routes despite the same CORS config, but I thought the CORS setup would work right out of the box..?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'reactor'