# Spring Boot @crossorigin not working for post

Tags: angular, spring-boot, post, get, cross-domain

I am working on Angular and Spring Boot.

I have setup the @CrossOrigin in Spring boot.
Also, I tried to setup the Global cross origin.

Also, then I tried to add it in the proxy js file of the angular.

I can see that only the GET is working.
But the POST request is not working at all.

Code details:
I have used Spring Boot and Spring Cloud Gateway for gateway purposes.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/core/area")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class AreaController {

    @Autowired
    AreaService areaService;

    // Other code stuff

}
```

This didn't work. So, I tried to set up the global configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CrossConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "HEAD", "OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

**On Angular side, I am able to access the Get method but I am not able to do the post call.**

Comment: Can you share your security config perhaps a class which extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ?

Comment: Hi @robert, I have added the example. It's really annoying issue. I am facing it for the last 2 days.

Comment: Try adding: `.allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");`

Comment: Thanks @robert. I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: I found one response in stackoverflow, That is working good. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148481/1780471](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148481/1780471)

Comment: That worked with the below answer. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148481/1780471](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63148481/1780471)